# Why is OpenCV always considering my image empty?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm trying to display an image using OpenCV. I have tried different images, but just get the title bar of the figure displayed, and seems that it considers my images empty.

I have used this command to read the image:

```
Mat im = imread("1.1.01.tiff");
```

And this command to display the image:

```
imshow("Hello", im);
```

Why are my images considered empty and not displayed?

Comment: it's just for .tiff? or also with .png etc?

Comment: first the obvious stuff... the path is valid and accessible? do you use `waitKey()` after `imshow`?

Comment: should "mshow("Hello", im);" be "imshow("Hello", im);"?

Comment: @TsvGis sure, just a typo

Comment: Could it be an issue with the file name of the .tiff with the "." e.g. 1.1.0. Try using underscores instead of "." e.g. 1_1_01.tiff